# XSLT 1.0 - Generate HTML table using elements having unequal attribute count but same attribute name

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to generate an HTML table using the attribute names as header and the attribute values as the data. However the elements that need to be looped do not have all the attributes present all the time. In such a scenario a blank `<td>` needs to be added to the table for all such non-available attribute values.

Below is a sample XML (a scaled down version with dummy values).

```
<root>
    <oelement attr="abc">
        <ielement attr="101">
            <child attr1="a" attr2="b" attr3="c" attr4="d" attr5="e" />
            <child attr1="e" attr2="f" attr3="g" attr4="h" attr5="i" />
        </ielement>
        <ielement attr="102">
            <child attr1="x" attr3="y" attr5="w" />
            <child attr1="j" attr3="k" attr5="l" />
        </ielement>
    </oelement>
    <oelement attr="pqr">
        <ielement attr="101">
            <child attr1="g" attr2="j" attr3="t" attr4="y" attr5="r" />
            <child attr1="d" attr2="q" attr3="a" attr4="c" attr5="b" />
        </ielement>
        <ielement attr="102">
            <child attr1="t" attr3="y" attr5="u" />
            <child attr1="i" attr3="o" attr5="p" />
        </ielement>
    </oelement>
    <oelement attr="xyz">
        <ielement attr="101">
            <child attr1="h" attr2="o" attr3="u" attr4="z" attr5="x" />
        </ielement>
        <ielement attr="103">
            <child attr1="q" attr3="w" attr5="e" />
        </ielement>
    </oelement>
</root>
```

Output HTML

[image: Output HTML Table]

I have tried to put together the following XSLT, however it does not match the attribute names in column header when loading the data in the appropriate column of the table.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <th>oelement</th>
                        <th>ielement</th>
                        <xsl:for-each select="//oelement[1]/ielement[1]/child[1]/@*">
                            <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name()" /></th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="child">
        <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::oelement/@attr" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ielement/@attr" /></td>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Need help in doing the column matching when adding value and inserting blank value for non-matching column. I am stuck with `XSLT 1.0` and cannot upgrade to `XSLT 2.0` for finding the `distinct-values()` of the attribute names.

Comment: Well, even with XSLT 1 there are processors implementing http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html or you can use Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no nice solution to do this in XLST 1.0.

You can use a key to achieve the desired effect, though:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="child-by-attr-name" match="child/@*" use="name(.)"/>

<xsl:template match="root">

    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                <!-- skipped for simplicity -->
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::oelement/@attr" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ielement/@attr" /></td>
        <xsl:variable name="current-child" select="."/>
        <xsl:for-each select="(//child/@*)[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('child-by-attr-name',name(.))[1])]">
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$current-child/@*[name(.) = name(current())]" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>    
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

The "trick" here is that the key will index all attributes (in every `child` element) by it's name. When you query the key by an attribute name, you get all occurrences of attributes with that name in document order. You can then use generate-id() to make sure you only get the first one of each name.

Answer (score 1):

The key to success is a proper way to loop through attribure names.

To do this, I used:

- A key (named `attrib`), matching `child` attributes and saving their names (`name()`).
- Two loops, one creating the header, and another printing attribute values.

To cope with changes in the context object in the template matching `child`,
and for readability, I used 2 variables:

- `curr` - the current `child` element.
- `nn` - the name of the current attribute.

So the whole script can look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:key name="attrib" match="child/@*" use="name()"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>oelement</th>
            <th>ielement</th>
            <xsl:for-each select="//child/@*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('attrib', name())[1])]">
              <th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
            </xsl:for-each> 
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="//child"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="child">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::oelement/@attr" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="ancestor::ielement/@attr" /></td>
      <xsl:variable name="curr" select="."/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//child/@*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('attrib', name())[1])]">
        <td>
          <xsl:variable name="nn" select="name()"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$curr/@*[name()=$nn]"/>
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```